# How to send blade as attachment in pdf format in laravel?

Tags: laravel, email, attachment, snappy

> I want to send blade file as attachment in mail with laravel. I am
>   writing below code for this but its not working.
>
> Below is my controller where i am getting data from form and then send
>   this data to another controller where my attachment function is
>   called.

```
$data = array('shareholders'=>$request->com_shareholder_count,'contract_send'=>$request->contract_send);
$to = $mail_log->to_email_id = $request->email_id;
$mail = Mail::to($to)->send(new SendMailable($data));
```

This is my SendMailable controller :

```
$director_info_pdf = view('directors_info',compact('data'))->render();
```

On return this variable it shows me error :

```
message: "Invalid view.", exception: "InvalidArgumentException",…}
exception: "InvalidArgumentException"
file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\caps_admin\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\Mailer.php"
line: 285
message: "Invalid view."
```

After this line i am writing code to attach my files. where i am sending some files other 3 files are directly send from folder. And last one is attached from blade file.

```
->attachdata($director_info_pdf, 'dynamic_data.pdf')
        ->attach( $public_path.'/'.'contract.pdf', [
                        'as' => 'contract.pdf',
                        'mime' => 'application/pdf',
                    ])
        ->attach($public_path.'/'.'HMRC.pdf',[
                        'as' => 'HMRC.pdf',
                        'mime' => 'application/pdf',
                    ])
         ->attach($public_path.'/'.'clientR3.pdf',[
                        'as' => 'contract1.pdf',
                        'mime' => 'application/pdf',
                    ]);
```

I am able to send mail with all 4 files as attachment. But when i am trying to open my files in mail rest 3 files are working as pdf. but `->attachdata($director_info_pdf, 'dynamic_data.pdf')`  this file get corrupted.

I dont know how to first change this file into pdf and then send as attachment.
I am using snappy for pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I dont know how to first change this file into pdf and then send as attachment. I am using snappy for pdf.

So that's the problem right there. You are attaching an HTML file, and simply naming it as if it's a PDF. That won't work. You do indeed need to generate this PDF from the HTML view that you render.

Here is the documentation for snappy:

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy#usage

I suggest you to read up on it, as the examples given there are pretty straight forward and easy to understand.

This is untested, **but if you've set up Snappy correctly**, based on your code, something like this should work:

```
$snappy = App::make('snappy.pdf');
$director_info_pdf = $snappy->getOutputFromHtml(view('directors_info',compact('data'))->render());
```

Comment: thanks for your reply @criss.but it shows me error of `Class 'App\Mail\App' not found`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php - `App` is not in the `App\Mail` namespace.

Comment: I am using alias of snappy in my namespace `use PDF` .`$snappy = PDF::make('snappy.pdf');`  after adding this its throws me error `call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Barryvdh\Snappy\IlluminateSnappyPdf' does not have a method 'make'`

Comment: Did you read the documentation? You're using alias of snappy, not alias of `App`, so your usage changes, as is described in the documentation. `$pdf = PDF::loadView('directors_info', compact($data));`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to send pdf as an attachment in your email without saving it in your system .

your can refer the following code to do this .

```
public function sendmail()
{
        $data["email"]='useremail@gmail.com';
        $data["client_name"]='user_name';
        $data["subject"]='sending pdf as attachment';

        //Generating PDF with all the post details

        $pdf = PDF::loadView('userdata');  // this view file will be converted to PDF

        //Sending Mail to the corresponding user

        Mail::send([], $data, function($message)use($data,$pdf) {
        $message->to($data["email"], $data["client_name"])
        ->subject($data["subject"])
        ->attachData($pdf->output(), 'Your_Post_Detail.pdf', [
                   'mime' => 'application/pdf',
               ])
        ->setBody('Hi, welcome user! this is the body of the mail');
        });
}
```

hope it helped you .

for better understanding you can follow this article

[how to send pdf as an attachment in email in laravel](https://www.studywithkishan.online/2020/09/send-pdf-attachment-on-mail-laravel.html)

Comment: The method `$pdf->output()` did the trick for me. Thank you. [Official Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#raw-data-attachments).  [The output() method not that well explained](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy).